# xhtml mobile w3validator error

Tags: html, xhtml, mobile

the w3 mobile html checker tool is giving me a severe warning and I'm not quite sure how to resolve it.

I have this link: `<a href="javascript:;" id="tab_search">My Link</a>`

I'm using jquery to add an onclick event so I don't need anything in the href tag. What should I put in the href tag to make html ignore it. I don't want to but a number sign (#) as it will move the browser to the top of the page.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Will `<a href="javascript:var x = 1;" id="tab_search">My Link</a>` do the trick?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the error still shows

Comment: I decided to just put an <a name="value"> above the link with #value in the href tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/). Don't assume JavaScript will be available, especially on mobile.

Comment: You raise a valid point however (I should have specified) in my instance the template is specifically designed for iphone/android, the percentage using other phones is less than 0.5% so I'm not to worried about those since ads won't show up on those phones anyways.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using your Doctype as XHTML 1.0 Strict. Try XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: There is no need for transitional for new web pages. Always use strict.

Comment: mobile templates use different doctypes as well